# How to save custom object data in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom object called `UserSettings`. Its a subclass NSObject with a few properties.
It has a method called `saveSettings` and all it does is save the properties to `NSUserDefaults`.

Everything works fine when I instantiate it and call the save method in my `ViewController` class. But I also need to save the settings in `AppDelegate` when application goes into background or terminates.

What would be the best practice for this typical scenario?
Should I use instantiate the object in `AppDelegate` and use `UIApplication sharedApplication` to access it as the TS here? [Saving data in custom class via AppDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767551/saving-data-in-custom-class-via-appdelegate)
Or should I create a static object?

Ignore my suggestions if it sounds weird as I'm still trying to get familiar with the design patterns.

Comment: There is no need to get the app delegate involved. Your view controller can register to receive notifications when the app enters the background.

Comment: Oh that's cool. Didn't know about that. Thanks. I'll go look it up.